# applicationDidBecomeActive in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The `applicationDidBecomeActive` method gets called when the app became active, is there a way that I can do this method for a certain UIViewController? I know there is `viewDidAppear` for view controllers but I'm searching for a method that is called when the app becomes active again AND is on a certain UIViewController. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can listen to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification:

```
@implementation CertainViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:)
   name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
   object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   removeObserver:self
   name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
   object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // Do something here
}

@end
```

Comment: Please add calls to super inside overriden methods.

Comment: From the headers: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;    // Called when the view is about to made visible. Default does nothing` and `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated; // Called when the view is dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing`. So no need to call `super`.