# ios How to get the bluetooth system pair peripheral notification

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

Here I'm working a iOS app development, using BLE module. But here I met a problem, How can I get the notification immediately when iOS system paired BLE peripheral device in background?

I make a way to solve satisfy this requirement, I set a timer to check the connected BLE devices every second, and find out what I need. But it's not the best method I think.

So Is there any other method to do this? such as add a notification observer?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can probably check for `didBecomeActive` - This will fire after your app has returned to the foreground once the system paring dialog has been dismissed

Comment: @Paulw11 Is the didBecomeActive a callback method of the CBCentralManager delegate?

Comment: Maybe it's not what I want. Thanks all the same.

Comment: No, it is an app delegate method (and there is a corresponding NSNotification posted).

Comment: Great. You mean I will get  a NSNotification when the iOS system connected to the BLE peripheral in background in the didBecomeActive callback method, right? So what's the name of the NSNotification?

Comment: Any time the system presents a dialog (such as a pairing dialog) you app will reign active and then become active. You kind of have to guess that it was the pairing dialog. It could also be a phone call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132734/applicationdidbecomeactive-in-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Hey I am facing the same problem @陈健Mark. Did you find any solution to this

Comment: Pity, I didn't get the best solution. It seems that there is no official notification type from iOS system. Currently, I still use the solution which check the BLE status periodically.